# Is there a way to create subsite based on another one, copying lists and workflows for them,..?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest, spfx, spfx-webparts

In Sharepoint Online, I'm trying to create a button that will trigger creating subsite and have all the lists and workflows based on one main list in root site.

E.g. there is two lists in root that have certain content type/columns, workflow and so on. How can I get them in subsite with exactly same name, columns, workflows?